# Java Not Using a parameter of the same class in a method

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

I have the following method inside the class `Player` that uses one of his emporiums available and sets it on a determined `City`

```
public void setEmporium(City city){

        Emporium emporium = getEmporiums().get(0);//gets the emporium from the player
        city.getEmporium().add(emporium);//adds it to the city
        LinkedList<Bonus> bonus = city.getBonus();
        for (int i=0;bonus!=null&&i<bonus.size();i++){
            bonus.get(i).applyBonus(player);//Error line
        }
        getEmporiums().remove(0);//removes the emporium from the player
    }
```

To correct the error of course i can just use the parameter player like this

```
public void setEmporium(City city,Player player){
```

but it isn't kind of redundant to use a parameter in its same class?

because when i test it would be like

```
Player player = new Player(1);
City city = new City(CityName.BURGEN,Color.YELLOW,4);
player.setEmporium(city, player);
```

and if i would create another object i would be able to do this

```
Player player2 = new Player(2);
player2.setEmporium(city, player);
```

This would mean that another player could build using emporiums from another player which shouldn't be possible, a player can only build using its own emporiums.

The only other solution that eclipse gives me is to create a local variable `Player player;` but then it says that it's not initialized, is there another way?

Comment: It's not 100% clear, but I think you want `bonus.get(i).applyBonus(this);`

Comment: thank you, i don't get why eclipse can't suggest that